# How can use Google App Engine with MS-SQL

Tags: python, sql-server, google-app-engine

I use

- python 2.7
- pyodbc module
- google app engine 1.7.1

I can use pydobc with python but the Google App Engine can't load the module. I get a no module named pydobc error.

How can I fix this error or how can use MS-SQL database with my local Google App Engine.

Comment: You just cannot use pyodbc it relies on 'c' based implementation and will not be useable on appengine. See this information. http://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/wiki/Building  . I you want to use appengine you will have to use CloudSQL as per answer below, create a web service on you MSSQL server that you appengine app can consume or don't use appengine.  (Note you can only make http based connections outbound - hence the comment below about not being able to connect to your own DB server.)

Answer (score 4):

The Google App Engine does *not* support access to your own SQL server, and does not support loading C-API libraries of your own.

You *can* use the Google Cloud SQL storage, which is implemented with MySQL databases, which you can access via their [Cloud SQL API for Python](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/cloud-sql/developers-guide).

Note that the `rdbms` module Google provides implements the [PEP 249 Python database API 2.0](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/) specification, just like the pyodbc module, so you should have no problems using it:

```
from google.appengine.api import rdbms

conn = rdbms.connect(instance=INSTANCE_NAME, database=DATABASE)
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM sometable')
```

Comment: very thanks Martjin Pieters

my database MS SQL not mysql can i this way mssql database?

Comment: @user1622511: No, as I stated, you cannot use your own server, and Google *only* offers the Google Cloud SQL storage or the Google Cloud storage; see https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/

Answer (score 0):

You could, at least in theory, replicate your data from the MS-SQL to the Google Cloud SQL database. It is possible create triggers in the MS-SQL database so that every transaction is reflected on your App Engine application via a REST API you will have to build.