# Backend for Android app

Tags: java, android, jsf, service, backend

I am creating website using JSF. Db is SQL Server. 
Now I want to create mobile client. Which technology should I use to create backend service for android client? It should simply handle mobile requests, store something in Db and return some data to mobile. I want it to be Java technology.

Comment: If you want it to be Java, JSP servlets seems perfect to archieve your goals.

Comment: You can output HTML and display it using a `WebView` or you can output JSON and let your client deserialize that into objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On android it's easy to read JSON and communicate with REST services. I strongly recommend something like that. SOAP / XML communication is much harder on android, way more plumbing

Here is a nice [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/giepu.html) how to create REST services via JAX-RS.

Comment: Yeah, JSON is great. You can handle that with `org.json` or `Gson`. Nobody does SOAP these days.

Comment: @Hegi thanks! What is the difference between this approach with JAX-RS  and Java servlets? And what about some kind of backends like Mobile backend starter and Parse? Can I use them to connect to my SQL Server Db and send data to android?

Comment: @android_dev Sadly i've never used Java servlets so i can't answer to that. Mobile backend starter is for Google Cloud. If you don't mind depending on Google, then go ahead, and try it, but I don't think  there is an easy way - if any - to connect from a google service to anything else than google. On the other hand, JAX-RS is not vendor specific, so from there, it's easy to use anything, including MS SQL Server.

Comment: @Hegi thanks! As http://stackoverflow.com/a/12108847/1635488 this answer states,Google only offers the Google Cloud SQL storage. I will try JAX RS,it seems that it is the best for Java. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Make REST services. There are lots of other things you can use alongside it like filters and servlets. To communicate with services( RESE, Servlets and Filters) you can use Ajax calls which can pass and receive JSON objects. There are lots of tutorials available on the net to accomplish this. As for the side note, Use Hibernate at the server side. It is very flexible and comes in handy when you are processing large data.

Comment: Thanks. I will try JAX RS. Where should I use Hibernate? For what purpose is it?

Comment: Usually when you pass JSON object using Ajax, it is better to store it in a class with each data member of it being an element form JSON object. Hibernate can be configured to store the whole class in database then.

Comment: Hi guys,App42(api.shephertz.com) provide complete Backend for your Android App.Please try this.